# Rotating a PNG file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, png

I have zero experience with manipulating image files of any sort with code, so I am lost about where to begin. All I need to do is open a PNG image file and save it rotated 90 degrees in objective-C. I am a quick learner, so even a push in the right direction would help immensely. I know this is no obscure function; any GUI image editor is capable of this, so I figure someone should be able to help. Thanks in advance!

(also, I have tagged this with iPhone to get more exposure; this is not something that needs to be iPhone-exclusive.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your "push":

1. Create a `CGImage` from the original file, using [ImageIO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html) (`CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`, `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`).
2. Create a bitmap context with transposed size, using [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101) (`CGBitmapContextCreate`).
3. Rotate the context's transformation matrix (`CGContextConcatCTM`)
4. Draw the original image into that context (`CGContextDrawImage`).
5. Create a new image from the bitmap context (`CGBitmapContextCreateImage`)
6. Save the image to a new file (`CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL`, `CGImageDestinationAddImage`, `CGImageDestinationFinalize`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [NSImage Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065337/nsimage-rotation) asked on Stackoverflow?